# Show part of an array once?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've got my array with multiple values in it and im doing a foreach statement to output all off the values into a style.

I've got 2 objects in the array that are the same across all rows and I need to show them once, at the top of everything as a header as you would.

The objects are:

```
[Manufacturer] => Samsung [Model] => Galaxy Nexus
```

My current code is:

```
foreach($array as $row) {
    echo $row->column1;
    echo $row->column2;
    echo $row->column3;
}
```

I thought maybe a while loop, however I'm not sure.  Also, this is being done in a CodeIgniter View and the query being pulled from a model if that makes any difference.

Comment: can you paste your array example with more details ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not totally clear what you are trying to do. I gather that you only want the first two values of the array printed once--at the beginning...

```
$i=0;
foreach($array as $row) {
    if($i==0){
        echo $row->column1;
        echo $row->column2;
    }
    echo $row->column3;
    $i++;
}
```